# The weak version of the memoriless property

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

In our group we are working with a probability distribution $X$ defined on a non-negative domain, satisfying the following property
$$
P\left[X>a\right]\ge P\left[X>a+t \mid X>t\right],
$$
where $a,t\ge 0$. We noticed some interesting properties that follow, and wonder if the above property is known in the community. Notice that in the case of equality, this is equivalent to the memoryless property.

Comment: To me, this seems related to increasing/decreasing failure rates (and their variants) that are classically used in reliability analysis. I do not know the name of your property but I think that it probably has one.

Comment: Have a look in Barlow/Proschan (1996), Mathematical Theory of Reliability, Chapter 2,

Comment: A similar term to failure rate is "hazard rate", both appear in this wikipedia article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_rate#Decreasing_failure_rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By googling

> "decreasing conditional survival" function

we find this term used e.g. in [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiMwLPCrcjhAhVLs6wKHVpiAiAQFjAAegQIABAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fshodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in%2Fbitstream%2F10603%2F41218%2F5%2Fchapter%25201.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2lx6iRTEXtOmXrDDlp3W9F) and a few others.